# Regular Expression how to get the value inside double quotes including double quotes

Tags: regex

This is want I want to achieve

a) `(123)` => `123`

b) `("123")` => `123`

c) `""123""` => `"123"`

d) `(""#12.20.AA"")` => `"#12.20.AA"`

valid characters inside the first double quotes are `"`, `.`, `#` and `:`

I tried with this `[\w\"\.:#=/\-\+\t\s]+` but obviously is returning `""123""` for the case b and `""#12.20.AA""` for case c and `"123"` for case b.

Any idea how to avoid the first double quotes and only the fist (and the same in the tail)?

Comment: What programming language or what regex implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression works for me:

```
\(?.*?"?("?[#:\d\.AA]+("(?="))?)"?.*\)?
```

You get your matches in the first matching group. The same regex with some comments:

```
\(?
.*?               # ? prevent the * to be eager
"?                # include the " if there
(                 # group 1 (your match)
    "?[#:\d\.AA]+
    ("(?="))?     # positive lookahead: include the first " in case there are two of them
)
"?
.*\)?
```

At [this demo link](https://regex101.com/r/oF0dJ8/1) you can easily experiment further with this expression.

In general, in case you need authoritative info on regex, this is a [pretty good link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes Matteo, this one covers all my cases \(?.*?"?("?[\w:\-#\d\.]+("(?="))?)"?.*\)?  including (""#12.20.anything:-"") thanks a lot!

Comment: This expression fails when it returns `#12.20.AA"` when matched with `(12.20.AA"")`, the result should be `#12.20.AA""`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($txt =~ /"/) {
    s/^[^"]*"//;
    s/"[^"]*$//;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.